# How to remove border of microsoft word in text image in opencv with python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have this picture which the border make by Microsoft word office :
[image]

I want to remove the border make by Microsoft word office to be like this :
[image]

I try this code but not working :

```
img = cv2.imread('border.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

crop = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
cv2.imwrite('border.png', crop)
cv2.imshow("Rotated", crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

so how I can do it by opencv and python ?

Comment: Do you understand what **your** code does? If so, it should be easy to see why it  doesn't work in your sample image

Comment: I would recommend to go step by step. Which step is not doing what it is supposed to? have you imshow the contours for example? or the threshold image? I suggest you first see the threshold and see if it shows what you want, then show the contour, is this the outer border? finally the bounding rect it will surround all the contour (including the contour) you need to change the x and y to x+10 or something like that, and then the w to w-10. this way it will be the inside part not the outside. 10 is just an example, you have to figure this number

Comment: you are right I must to add to x and y a number , thank for help @api55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpliest way would be using ROI as you did.

```
cv::Mat workingRegion = img(cv::Rect(x_coord,y_coord,width,height), img.type());
```

In images created with software like microsoft online borders are always located in the same part of image. You could cut it off.

To detect border i would use OTSU threshold

```
cv::threshold(img,img,100,255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

I would produce better results. Add some images so I can help you better.

Comment: you Are right , I must to knew the  software like microsoft online borders and then to add a number to x and y , thanks for help it work